# Bulk upload from Excel in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to bulk upload from an Excel file using the following query:

```
BULK INSERT TempRevenueForecast 
   FROM 'E:\RevenueTracker\Demo\UserTemplate.xls' 
   WITH (FORMATFILE = 'E:\RevenueTracker\Demo\TRF.FMT');
GO
```

But, I'm getting this error:

> Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 2

How can I solve it?

Comment: BULK INSERT will not load an Excel file. You either need to save as a text file first or use OPENROWSET, much like these examples (the first ones that appeared in Google when I searched) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5942b056-7985-4cc0-9628-6dcbc6f6bda1/bulk-insert-for-loading-xls-excel-files?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the table TempRevenueForecast in edit mode (right-click-table - edit top 200 rows) in SSMS, you can just copy-paste the excel data over.

That's a very handy feature of SSMS.

Otherwise, use OpenRowSet:

```
INSERT INTO [TempRevenueForecast ] ([Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4])

SELECT A.[Column1], A.[Column2], A.[Column3], A.[Column4]
FROM OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=E:\RevenueTracker\Demo\UserTemplate.xls;HDR=YES', 'select * from [Sheet1$]') AS A;
```

For that to work, the Microsoft Access Database Engine (ACE) components must be installed.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734
or 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255